# How to remove the serpentine belt on a 2007 Chevy Malibu

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, drive-belt

I know where to get the tool I need but am in need of a diagram so I know where it fits.

EDIT: It has the V6 in it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the engine in your car, it could look differently. Below is the routing on the 4-cylinder engine. The V6 routing is just below it with the red arrow pointing to the tensioner. There should be a square hole in the end of the tensioner right at the pulley which you can place the tool. Lever it so you can loosen the belt and remove it.

[image]

Here's for the v6:

[image]

And here's a video which might be of some assistance: https://youtu.be/XJD8mw0xISo